# Thinktecture IdentityServer V3 admin page

Tags: thinktecture

I am new to the IdentityServer V3. I am not sure where to find the admin page where we provide the clientID ,clientSecret and the scope etc similar to v2. Is that changed in v3? If so can someone point me to some basics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [tutorial identityServer v3 membershipreboot-angularjs-webapi-2-and-mvc-mix](http://cedric-dumont.com/tutorials/identityserver-v3-membershipreboot-angularjs-webapi-2-and-mvc-mix-it-introduction/). You will be most interested in Part 1. There is also sample code for this tutorial (you will find link on page).

Thinktecture has greate samples repository. Try [IdentityServer3.Samples MembershipReboot](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MembershipReboot) example, it may be usefull for you.

Comment: Neither https://cedric-dumont.com/tutorials/identityserver-v3-membershipreboot-angularjs-webapi-2-and-mvc-mix-it-introduction/ tutorial nor  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MembershipReboot example do not describe Admin Page for Client Configuration

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim, maybe you will found [this](https://brockallen.com/2014/04/09/introducing-thinktecture-identitymanager/) or [this](https://github.com/IdentityManager/IdentityManager) helpful.

Comment: Both this links are also not related to the question about ADMIN page for CLIENT configuration. ALso, when providing a link, it's better to describe the name of the article or at least full URL(which often include the article description. Hiding the title by "this" link wastes reader time - I have to open link just to find that it is unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Their are two https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin and https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Admin.EntityFramework repositories , both implemented backend API.

From https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/110 brockallen commented on Oct 28, 2014

> I think this issue requires me to split the EF repo into two: 1) for
>   the EF entities, and 2) implementation of the Core interfaces that
>   maps back and forth from core to EF entities. Then I'd add a third
>   project/repo that references the EF entities and build interfaces that
>   map back/forth to the Core.Admin interfaces/models

You either need to implement UI by yourself, or buy a AdminUi product https://www.identityserver.com/products/